# How to Auto Click href to select something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the Code that I copy from a website

I want to auto select the size, for example 12

I found lot of ways and none work

```html
<span id="size_selection_list">
    <a title="Size 07.5" value="07.5" data-modelsize="07_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">07.5</a>
    <a title="Size 08.0" value="08.0" data-modelsize="08_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.0</a>
    <a title="Size 08.5" value="08.5" data-modelsize="08_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.5</a>
    <a title="Size 09.0" value="09.0" data-modelsize="09_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.0</a>
    <a title="Size 09.5" value="09.5" data-modelsize="09_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.5</a>
    <a title="Size 10.0" value="10.0" data-modelsize="10_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.0</a>
    <a title="Size 10.5" value="10.5" data-modelsize="10_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.5</a>
    <a title="Size 11.0" value="11.0" data-modelsize="11_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.0</a>
    <a title="Size 11.5" value="11.5" data-modelsize="11_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.5</a>
    <a title="Size 12.0" value="12.0" data-modelsize="12_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.0</a>
    <a title="Size 12.5" value="12.5" data-modelsize="12_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.5</a>
    <a title="Size 13.0" value="13.0" data-modelsize="13_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.0</a>
    <a title="Size 13.5" value="13.5" data-modelsize="13_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.5</a>
    <a title="Size 14.0" value="14.0" data-modelsize="14_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">14.0</a>
    <a title="Size 15.0" value="15.0" data-modelsize="15_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">15.0</a>
    <a title="Size 16.0" value="16.0" data-modelsize="16_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">16.0</a>
    <a title="Size 17.0" value="17.0" data-modelsize="17_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">17.0</a>
    <a title="Size 18.0" value="18.0" data-modelsize="18_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">18.0</a>
</span>
```

Comment: <span id="size_selection_list">
   
    <a title="Size 12.0" value="12.0" data-modelsize="12_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.0</a>
    
    <a title="Size 12.5" value="12.5" data-modelsize="12_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.5</a>
    
    <a title="Size 18.0" value="18.0" data-modelsize="18_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">18.0</a></span>

Comment: @unknown Thanks for editing (y)

Comment: Please share some of the many ways you tried that did not work for you

Comment: $('.size_selection_list a:contains("12.0")').trigger('click'); @mplungjan here is one thanks

Comment: `document.querySelector("[title='Size 12.0']").click();` or `$("[title='Size 12.0']").trigger("click");` or `$("[value='12.0']").trigger("click");` or `$("[data-modelsize='12_0']").trigger("click");`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks Boss Would you mind tell me how this work ?? I am new to Javascript Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: can I ask you one more thing??

Comment: document.querySelector("[title='Size 12.0']").click(); document.getElementById('pdp_addtocart_button').click() location.href="footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?"; location.href="javascript:inventoryCheck_panel.open();"

Comment: can i dely each action? But without selecting the size it wouldn't allow me to add to cart, without adding to cart, i can't click check out button. Is there anyway I can do it step by step one follow one? thanks I tried set time interval and time out it wouldn't work thanks  @mplungjan

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: You cannot change the location twice. The second location change will not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit the [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) page to see what you can do

PS: Links do not have a native `value` attribute

```js
// visualisation

$("a").on("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't follow the link
  var $link = $(this); // save for later
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($link.attr("title")); // add to cart here
  },1000); 
})

// each of these work / choose ONE

// I prefer this jQuery one
$("[data-modelsize='12_0']").trigger("click");


// plain JavaScript:
// document.querySelector("[title='Size 12.0']").click(); // or 

// other jQuery examples
// $("[title='Size 12.0']").trigger("click"); // or 
// $("[value='12.0']").trigger("click"); // or
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="size_selection_list">
    <a title="Size 07.5" value="07.5" data-modelsize="07_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">07.5</a>
    <a title="Size 08.0" value="08.0" data-modelsize="08_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.0</a>
    <a title="Size 08.5" value="08.5" data-modelsize="08_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.5</a>
    <a title="Size 09.0" value="09.0" data-modelsize="09_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.0</a>
    <a title="Size 09.5" value="09.5" data-modelsize="09_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.5</a>
    <a title="Size 10.0" value="10.0" data-modelsize="10_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.0</a>
    <a title="Size 10.5" value="10.5" data-modelsize="10_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.5</a>
    <a title="Size 11.0" value="11.0" data-modelsize="11_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.0</a>
    <a title="Size 11.5" value="11.5" data-modelsize="11_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.5</a>
    <a title="Size 12.0" value="12.0" data-modelsize="12_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.0</a>
    <a title="Size 12.5" value="12.5" data-modelsize="12_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.5</a>
    <a title="Size 13.0" value="13.0" data-modelsize="13_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.0</a>
    <a title="Size 13.5" value="13.5" data-modelsize="13_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.5</a>
    <a title="Size 14.0" value="14.0" data-modelsize="14_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">14.0</a>
    <a title="Size 15.0" value="15.0" data-modelsize="15_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">15.0</a>
    <a title="Size 16.0" value="16.0" data-modelsize="16_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">16.0</a>
    <a title="Size 17.0" value="17.0" data-modelsize="17_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">17.0</a>
    <a title="Size 18.0" value="18.0" data-modelsize="18_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">18.0</a>
</span>
```

Comment: I tried the code It is not working, auto selected the size but not add cart afterward :(

Comment: Do use jQuery all the way. What does your comment mean?

Comment: Ask a new question. The question was "How to auto click a link with a specific attribute" and the next step may not be possible if it involved changing the page location too

Comment: I can't Ask a New Question :( maybe I am new to here. 1, Auto Selec Size 2, Auto Add to cart 3, Auto Redirect to Cart Page 4, Auto Redirect to Checkout Page. I got all the code for these 4 command but I can connect it together and I need to type it separately :( Thankssss

Comment: You cannot do the 4th on the client since the script runs on one page only. You seem to need a ScriptMonkey script.

Comment: What is ScriptMonkey script about?? How it works I search on google and not understand that :(

Comment: There is no other way out? :(

Comment: No on a client. You could try on a server

Comment: console.log($link.attr("title")); // add to cart here

Comment: What do you mean in this part ?? you mean i need to erase the code and use the add to cart code instead? thanks boss

Comment: Yes exactly - I do not have your buttons so I just showed the click executed

Comment: document.getElementById('pdp_addtocart_button').click() I put this code instead of  console.log($link.attr("title")); ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Attribute Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). Try this:

```js
$("#size_selection_list a[value='12.0']").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="size_selection_list">
    <a title="Size 07.5" value="07.5" data-modelsize="07_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">07.5</a>
    <a title="Size 08.0" value="08.0" data-modelsize="08_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.0</a>
    <a title="Size 08.5" value="08.5" data-modelsize="08_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">08.5</a>
    <a title="Size 09.0" value="09.0" data-modelsize="09_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.0</a>
    <a title="Size 09.5" value="09.5" data-modelsize="09_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">09.5</a>
    <a title="Size 10.0" value="10.0" data-modelsize="10_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.0</a>
    <a title="Size 10.5" value="10.5" data-modelsize="10_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">10.5</a>
    <a title="Size 11.0" value="11.0" data-modelsize="11_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.0</a>
    <a title="Size 11.5" value="11.5" data-modelsize="11_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">11.5</a>
    <a title="Size 12.0" value="12.0" data-modelsize="12_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.0</a>
    <a title="Size 12.5" value="12.5" data-modelsize="12_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">12.5</a>
    <a title="Size 13.0" value="13.0" data-modelsize="13_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.0</a>
    <a title="Size 13.5" value="13.5" data-modelsize="13_5" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">13.5</a>
    <a title="Size 14.0" value="14.0" data-modelsize="14_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">14.0</a>
    <a title="Size 15.0" value="15.0" data-modelsize="15_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">15.0</a>
    <a title="Size 16.0" value="16.0" data-modelsize="16_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">16.0</a>
    <a title="Size 17.0" value="17.0" data-modelsize="17_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">17.0</a>
    <a title="Size 18.0" value="18.0" data-modelsize="18_0" data-ssi="false" data-sfs="false" data-backorder="false" class="grid_size in-stock" href="javascript:void(0);">18.0</a>
    </span>
```

Comment: Thanks that's work Would you mind tell me how this work ??

Comment: RTM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @AnfieldWong: I shared Attribute Selector link. Please go through.

Comment: can I ask you one more thing??

Comment: document.querySelector("[title='Size 12.0']").click();

document.getElementById('pdp_addtocart_button').click() 

location.href="https://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?"

location.href="javascript:inventoryCheck_panel.open();"

Comment: can i dely each action? But without selecting the size it wouldn't allow me to add to cart, without adding to cart, i can't click check out button. Is there anyway I can do it step by step one follow one? thanks I tried set time interval and time out it wouldn't work thanks @Unknown